# Powershell open Ps1 if true

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

What am I doing wrong here? I am trying to open a second PS1 file if True but an error is thrown (shown below).

```
#ABOUT

#GLOBALS
$userID = "admin"
$pswrd = "test"
$name = Read-Host 'What is your username?'
$pass = Read-Host 'And your password?' #-AsSecureString | ConvertFrom-SecureString

#$script = '.\sdsSysMain.ps1'

if($name -eq $userID -and $pass -eq $pswrd) #or blank?
{ 
  #write-host "Well done! You're in. "

  #Start-Sleep -s 5
  Powershell -noexit ".\sdsSysMain.ps1"
}
elseif($name -ne $userID -or $pass -ne $pswrd)
{ 
  write-host "Login Failed... :(" 
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
powershell.exe : The term '.\sdsSysMain.ps1' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function
At C:\Users\1234\Documents\Projects\sdsSys\sdsSysLogin.ps1:19 char:15
+     Powershell <<<<  -noexit ".\sdsSysMain.ps1"
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (The term '.\sds...mdlet, function:String) [],    
RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,  
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:17
+ .\sdsSysMain.ps1 <<<< 
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\sdsSysMain.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is rather self-explanatory. The script doesn't find `sdsSysMain.ps1` in the current working directory. You can output the current working directory in your script like this:

```
(Get-Location).Path
```

If you want to run `sdsSysMain.ps1` from the same directory as the script calling it, change this:

```
Powershell -noexit ".\sdsSysMain.ps1"
```

into this:

```
$scriptPath = Split-Path -Parent $script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
Powershell -NoExit -File "$scriptPath\sdsSysMain.ps1"
```

Comment: Thanks this appears to work. What a simple mistake I was making. However once sdsSysMain opens nothing happens. I think it could be because I have these objects below in the sdsSysMain and the login script above has not been notified of these object declarations. Is this true? After these objects I use a simple switch. $Close = New-Object System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription "&Close", `
    "Close"

#ORDER CHOICES ARGS
$Options = [System.Management.Automation.Host.ChoiceDescription[]]($Close)
#ORDER ON UI

$SelectApp = $host.ui.PromptForChoice($title, $message, $options)